# how can i get spaces between listbox items in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

i have a listbox binding data from database in that listbox have 2 fields category and items fields but i want to have a space between values of category and items like this

```
listbox2

category  items
   1        A1
   2        B2
```

i tried below code but not getting the spaces

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select category,items from lstitems", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

string str1 = "category";
string str2 = "items";
string str3 = str1 + "\t" + "\t" + str2;
listbox2.Items.Add(str3.ToString());


for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{

    string str = dt.Rows[i][0] + "\t"  + "\t" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
     listbox2.Items.Add(str.ToString());

}
```

can anyone help me out

```
.aspx page:

    <asp:ListBox ID="listbox2" runat="server" DataTextField="" Height="188px" Width="129px" SelectionMode="Multiple" style="margin-top: 14px"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: I think there aren't real tabulators in html. Maybe you should consider using a table. Another option could be to use some `&nbsp;` instead of the tabulator.

Comment: i tried but its not working it will print between values &nbsp; in result

Comment: OK, my fault - thought it's being translated in the ListBox. Why not just put some empty spaces between the two columns?

Comment: i tried empty spaces in passing command ("Select category+' '+items from lstitems") like this but its raise syntax error can you please tell me another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the two parts of each item by inserting unbreakable spaces between them. In order to get a nice column alignment, you should set the font of the ListBox to a monospace type.

In the markup:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listbox2" runat="server" Font-Names="Lucida Console,Courier New" ... />
```

To get both "columns" left-aligned:

```
const int Col1Width = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string part1 = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    string part2 = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    listbox2.Items.Add(part1.PadRight(Col1Width , '\u00A0') + part2);
}
```

To get the two "columns" centered:

```
private string PadCenter(string source, int length, char space)
{
    int spaces = length - source.Length;
    int padLeft = spaces / 2 + source.Length;
    return source.PadLeft(padLeft, space).PadRight(length, space);
}

...

const int Col1Width = 12;
const int Col2Width = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string part1 = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    string part2 = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    listbox2.Items.Add(PadCenter(part1, Col1Width, '\u00A0') + PadCenter(part2, Col2Width, '\u00A0'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it help me a lot